# Add a new row on basis of column values in R

Tags: r, dataframe, data-science, preprocessor

I am trying to get my head around this simple preprocessing task in R. I am trying to get the ideal value column as a row titled ideal in Product ID. I think the image below will shed more light on it.

[image]

```
> dput(df)

structure(list(Consumer = c(43L, 43L, 43L, 43L, 43L, 41L, 41L, 
41L, 41L, 41L), Product = c(106L, 992L, 366L, 257L, 548L, 106L, 
992L, 366L, 257L, 548L), Firm = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L), Juicy = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L
), Sweet = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L), Ideal_Firm = c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Ideal_Juicy = c(1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), Ideal_Sweet = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))
```

Comment: Please use ```dput()``` and post the sample of your data frame. It will make things easier.

Comment: Hi thanks for highlighting. I have updated with dput()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is a solution:

```
df <- data.frame(
  Consumer = c(rep(43, 5), rep(41, 5)),
  Product = rep(sample(100:900,size = 5, replace = F), 2),
  Firm = c(sample(rep(0:1, 5), replace = T)),
  Juicy = c(sample(rep(0:1, 5), replace = T)),
  Sweet = c(sample(rep(0:1, 5), replace = T)),
  Ideal_Firm = 1, 
  Ideal_Juicy = c(rep(1, 5), rep(2, 5)), 
  Ideal_Sweet = c(rep(1, 5), rep(0, 5))
)

library(dplyr)
df <- merge(
  # Bind the observation...
  df %>% select(Consumer:Sweet) %>% 
    pivot_wider(id_cols = Consumer,names_from = Product,values_from = Firm:Sweet),
  # ... to the ideal
  df %>% group_by(Consumer) %>% 
    # Here I put mean, but it could be 1, median, min, max... If I understood correctly, it has to be 1?
    summarise(across(Ideal_Firm:Ideal_Sweet, ~mean(.x))) %>%
    # Rename so the column name has the form [characteristic]_ideal instead of Ideal_[characteristic]
    # remove prefix Ideal_ ...
    rename_at(.vars = vars(starts_with("Ideal_")),
              .funs = funs(sub("Ideal_", "", .))) %>%
    # ... add _Ideal as a suffix instead
    rename_at(vars(-Consumer), function(x) paste0(x,"_Ideal"))
)

# Then manipulate to get into long form again
df <- df %>% pivot_longer(cols = !Consumer) %>%
  separate(name, c("Characteristic", "Product")) %>%
  pivot_wider(id_cols = Consumer:Product, names_from = Characteristic, values_from = value)
df
```

Comment: Hi Rosalie, brilliant answer just one thing missing, the ideal values are the same for each customer but they do differ overall. I was thinking if there could be some condition for this.

Comment: Hello Inshal, I modified the input dataset to have different "ideal", and it still works! I group_by(Consumer) when I do the ideal dataset, so it gives a different mean() for each consumer. See edited answer above. Did I misunderstand your question?

Comment: This looks good. Ill see if it works on my main data frame. Thanks a lot, Rosalie!!

Comment: You're welcome! I added a few line to change the prefix "Ideal_" to become a suffix "_Ideal", so it matches your dataset column names.